# Find object's location in an area using computer vision

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition

I'm trying to see how to detect the location of a soccer ball in the field using the live camera. What are some ways to achieve this?

1- Assuming we have a fixed camera with a wide shot. How to find the ball location on the actuall field?

2- A camera is zooming into the ball. But we know the location of the camera and maybe it's turning angle. Can we estimate the ball location on the field using this info? Or maybe we need additional info? Can we do it with two cameras as reference points?

Any thoughts would be helpful.

[image]

[image]